# how to apply class according to the filename?

Tags: php, css

i have created an application where i want to apply active class on active page. Like if fike name starts with me_ then how can i apply class "active" to it.

here is my code:

```
$pageAttr       =   basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
$files          =   array("me_dashboard.php","me_my_team.php","me_others.php","me_inbox.php","me_outbox.php"); 


<li class="<?php echo($pageAttr == $files[0] || $pageAttr == $files[1] || $pageAttr == $files[2] || $pageAttr == $files[3] || $pageAttr == $files[4]) ? "active":"" ?>"><a href="me_dashboard.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i> Me</a></li>
```

this is not correct code to use. Please suggest me some other ways to achieve the solution in PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not correct code to use"? You can replace the line with `in_array()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have array of files like this

```
$files = array("me_dashboard.php",
                "me_my_team.php",
                "me_others.php",
                "me_inbox.php",
                "me_outbox.php"
          );
```

Than you can use `in_array()` like

```
<li class="<?php echo (in_array(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), $files) ? 'active' : '')?>">
```

It will be even better if you port the `class=` attribute in the `if` condition as well, so that you do not get an empty `class=""` markup.

---

If you want to refactor your code more, consider porting entire code in a `function`, and then `return` the value if condition goes `true`.

---

As commented, you wanted to fetch the prefix of the file than you can use `substr()`

```
<?php
    $page_name = 'me_dashboard.php';
    $fetch_prefix = substr($page_name, 0, 3);
    echo $fetch_prefix;
?>
<li class="<?php echo (($fetch_prefix == 'me_') ? 'active' : '')?>">A</li>
```

[**Demo**](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/ecz-xv7) - [**Code**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ecz-xv7)

Comment: Cant believe same answer .. let me delete mine :)

Comment: is it possible to apply class "active" if file name starts with "me_"??

Comment: can u please help me how do i use it?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
<?php
$pageAttr       =   basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
$files          =   array("me_dashboard.php","me_my_team.php","me_others.php","me_inbox.php","me_outbox.php"); 

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $class_text = "";
    if($file==$pageAttr)
    {
        $class_text = ' class="active" ';
    }
    ?>
        <li <?php echo $class_text;?> ><a href="<?php echo $file;?>"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i> Me</a></li>
    <?php
}
?>
```